# Lightening effect with javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to use recursion in JavaScript to produce an infinite loop. In fact, I desire to give an image a come-and-go effect, endlessly.

Let's take a look at some code first :

```
function lightening(){
    $('#pic_holder').fadeOut(250).fadeIn(250);
    setTimeout('lightening', 250);
}
```

This function, as it's written, should

- apply the `fadeOut(250)` and `fadeIn(250)` effects ;
- engage the `setTimeout` function which in its turn must call recursively the `lightening` function, henceforth re-applying the [*fadeOut-fadeIn effect* and *setTimeout*] block of code.

This, you'll agree, should go ad infinitum, but it doesn't.

Here's the [full test code, with HTML](http://jsfiddle.net/K7JMj/27/), as you can notice, it applies the fadeOut-fadeIn effect only once.

What am I doing wrong ?

Comment: Note that the calls to "fadeOut" and "fadeIn" will return immediately, even though the effect will take 500 milliseconds. If you start the next cycle in 250 milliseconds, you'll be building up a backlog.

Comment: Also note that the code in your question is not recursive. Asynchrony and recursion are different things entirely.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi I would say it's both.

Comment: @basilikum - How so? According to [wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Recursion#Recursion_in_computer_science): `Recursion in computer programming is exemplified when a function is defined in terms of simpler, often smaller versions of itself. The solution to the problem is then devised by combining the solutions obtained from the simpler versions of the problem.`

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi : it's a call of the function itself inside its own code, that's not recursive ?

Comment: @tjameson it's a function that invokes itself. It doesn't do it directly but by passing itself to an asynchronous function which then calls it later on. To me that is still recursive. Or what is the exact  definition of recursion?

Comment: @basilikum, IMHO `lightening()` is not called recursively. Since the invocation goes through `setTimeout()`, the stack is unwound. Returning from the `n`th invocation of the function does not give control back to its `n-1`th invocation.

Comment: @basilikum - Also from wikipedia: `The main disadvantage is often that the algorithm may require large amounts of memory if the depth of the recursion is very large.`. This seems to imply a stack (I'm ignoring TCO here), where each invocation returns state. This is just emulating `setInterval`, which I hope we can agree is **not** recursion.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi - Right, I've edited my comment to say I'm explicitly ignoring TCO, since that's an optimization of a recursive algorithm. The function *could* be an asynchronous, recursive function if it did something more interesting: doStuff(args..., nextCallback), but it would have to actually mutate some kind of state. In short, I agree, it's something else entirely.

Comment: @FrédéricHamidi you both have good points. So that means, that both of these function are not recursive? http://jsfiddle.net/mzKHh/

Comment: @basilikum, to me `b()` is recursive, but `a()` is not.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

What you *really* should do is this:

```
function lightening(){
  $('#pic_holder').fadeOut(250).fadeIn(250, lightening);
}
```

That'll make the next cycle start when the fade-in has completed. Mixing your own timeouts with timeouts implied by jQuery animation calls is tricky and usually unnecessary. In your case, you're starting a new cycle halfway through a previous one, which really won't take effect until 250 milliseconds later.

Comment: This is sexy.  Nice answer.

Answer (score 6):

The first argument to `setTimeout` can either be:

- a function to be called; or
- a string of JavaScript to be executed

Your function isn't being called, because you just have its name in a string.  Remove the single quotes.

```
function lightening(){
    $('#pic_holder').fadeOut(250).fadeIn(250);
    setTimeout(lightening, 250);
}
```

[See the Mozilla Documentation](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/window.setTimeout) for proper usage.

Comment: and the timer interval should probably be 500 milliseconds, not 250

Answer (score 3):

Instead of using 2 competing timers that will either have intermittent bugs or have to be too generous, use the callback:

```
function lightening(){
    $('#pic_holder').fadeOut(250).fadeIn(250, lightening);
}
```

Comment: +1 for using callback.  I removed my answer suggesting this since yours came first.  Here are the notes I had added to my post: This solution allows for the fact that the timings aren't guaranteed. A timer guarantees a MINIMUM amount of time until an event happens, but based on processing, it could be more. Similarly, you're not guaranteed that the animations start immediately.

This might be splitting hairs, but I think it's worth at least noting and adding to the answer list.

Answer (score 1):

Remove quote.

```
setTimeout(lightening, 250);
```